# Javafx get font style for a given font

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I want to get font style(bold, italics...) for the given fonts.

Currently i am getting the font list in a combobox using javafx.scene.text.Font.getFamilies() and now I want to get font style for each font, like that in notepad.

can any one guide me how to get list of those fonts style and use that to set the property for a given TextArea named demo_text_area.